# @role directive for multiple roles in Zizaco/entrust laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, entrust

I am using [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) laravel package and now I want to use **@role** directive in blade template to show an item only to some defined roles like this :

```
@role('developer,administrator')
<li><a href="/admin/permission">Permissions</a></li>
@endrole
```

But this does not work. is it possible ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I read some code and looks like code below will work for You:

```
@role(['developer','administrator'])
<li><a href="/admin/permission">Permissions</a></li>
@endrole
```

Because You are sending array to this function: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/src/Entrust/Traits/EntrustUserTrait.php#L90